# Handlebars.js Populate dropdown / subnav with Json

Tags: javascript, json, handlebars.js

I'm trying to populate a dropdown list, using handle bar and Json.
I'm not understanding how to structure Json in order to populate my sub navigation.

Really helpful would be understanding how to fix the json structure, as I'm not a big expert of handlebars.
Would be lovely to understand what I'm mistaking!

```js
var data = {

  "title": "TITLE",
  "navItems": [{
      "mainnav": [{
          "title": "Home",
          "class": "subnav webfont-arrow_down",
          "id": " ",
          "href": "index.html"
        },
        {
          "title": "About us",
          "class": "",
          "id": " ",
          "href": "about-us.html",

          //SUB NAV STARTS HERE!!!!       
          "subnav": [{
              "title": "About us",
              "class": "",
              "href": "#"
            },
            {
              "title": "The School",
              "href": "about-us.html#TheSchool"
            },
            {
              "title": "Services",
              "href": "about-us.html#Services"
            },
            {
              "title": "The Curriculum",
              "href": "about-us.html#TheCurriculum"
            }

          ]
        },

        {
          "title": "Photo Gallery",
          "class": "",
          "id": " ",
          "href": "gallery.html"
        },
        {
          "title": "ofsted",
          "class": "",
          "id": " ",
          "href": "ofsted.html"
        },

        {
          "title": "contacts",
          "class": "",
          "id": " ",
          "href": "contacts.html"
        }
      ]



    }

  ]
};






var t = Handlebars.compile($('#t').html());
$('body').append(t(data));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/handlebars.js/4.0.12/handlebars.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script id="t" type="text/x-handlebars">
  <nav class="nav-main">

    {{#each global.navItems}}

    <div class="nav-subnav">
      <ul>
        {{#each mainnav}}
        <li class="nav-navItem">
          <a href="{{href}}" class="{{class}} nav-navLink">{{title}}</a> {{#if subnav}}
          <div class="subnav">
            <ul class="">
              {{#each subnav}}
              <li class="nav-navItem">
                <a href="{{href}}" class="{{class}}" class="nav-navLink">{{title}}</a> {{!-- {{#if subnav}} {{/if}} --}}
              </li>
              {{/each}}
            </ul>
          </div>
          {{/if}}

        </li>
        {{/each}}
      </ul>




    </div>

    {{/each}}

  </nav>



</script>
```

Comment: Hi. what's the output you're getting with your current code?

Comment: @MoA currenly nothing as I have an error on the json code :-(

Comment: Can you remove `global` from `{{#each global.navItems}}` and try?